# Maximum hex file limit for At89c51

Tags: microcontroller

I have hex file of size 6kb. Can i load this on at89c51 microcontroller. I have tried this on proteus. It runs successfully. Will it run properly on hardware as at89c51 has only 4kb programmable flash memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hex files are human-readable ASCII, and the size on a disk may be larger because of disk storage granularity.

To find out if it will fit, open the file in a text editor and look at the addresses.. the highest address in a 4K byte internal memory 8051 is 0xFFF.

Here, from [Keil's documentation](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/1584/), is an explanation of the Intel format:

[image]

Note that there can be **gaps** in the addresses from line to line, and that the length of the line may be short or long (up to some limit specified in the original Intel docs) and that the line length can vary from one line to the next (usually it's the last line or the last line before a gap that is shorter) so it's not possible to reliably guess the binary file size from the hex file size.

Generally speaking, though, since each byte is represented by two 1-byte ASCII characters, and there is some overhead in each line (13 bytes) it should fit easily if there are no gaps in the addresses. On the other hand, if it was (say) compiled or assembled for a 32K byte processor there could easily be things stuffed up at the top of memory-- so it would not be possible to program it into a smaller micro.